# Angular Need help set value to mat-select

Tags: angular

Can someone help me fix the issue with mat-select

I would like to set the initial values using the below

```
  orders: Order[] = [{"dish":"steak-0"},{"dish":"tacos-2"}];
```

Currently both are set to Tacos. Don't know how to set them using value from orders

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xh3kna?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-form-example.html)

Comment: Don't understand why the question attracted a down vote? do they only want rocket science questions?

Comment: I can't ask any new question. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your both selects have the same value is: `name="food"`. If you name them dynamically like this they will have different initial values: `name="food{{q}}"`

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xh3kna-t4vzts?file=src/app/select-form-example.html)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll delete my answer since it's not correct actually